# Making a commit from a pre-receive hook - error: failed to push some refs

Tags: bash, git, githooks

I have pretty simple git deployment setup for a website as explained [here](https://medium.com/@francoisromain/vps-deploy-with-git-fea605f1303b):

- A bare repository where multiple people commit to
- A "normal" repository with a working directory that is accessible via a URL (I'll call it prime)
- The bare repository has a commit hook. Whenever someone commits something, the prime repository pulls all changes, from the bare repository. Essentially updating the website from a push.

However, sometimes files on the prime repository get updated by some scripts. So whenever someone pushes to the bare repository, I'd like to create an automatic commit from prime to the bare repo containing the changes.

I've played around with the various commit hooks. From my understanding I could do the following:

- When someone pushes to the bare repository
- Have a pre-receive hook that checks for changes on the prime repository
- If there are any changes commit them to the bare repository
- In the post-update hook, pull the commits of the user to the prime repository

pre-receive:

```sh
cd ../public || exit # Go to the prime repository
unset GIT_DIR

if [[ `git status --porcelain` ]]; then

    echo "-> Changes on server detected, pushing to master..."

    git add . # Add all changes
    git commit -m "Auto-Commit from pre-receive hook" # Commit them
    git push origin master # Push to bare repository
else
    echo "-> No changes on server detected..."
fi

exec git-update-server-info
```

post-update:

```sh
cd ../public || exit # Go to the prime repository
unset GIT_DIR
echo "Pulling..."
git pull origin master # Pull user changes into prime

exec git-update-server-info
```

It kind of works. When there are no changes in the prime repository everything updates correctly. However, when there are changes and the hook triggers a commit, I would expect to get the message `Your branch is 1 commit behind, please pull`. Instead I get an error:

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (failed to update ref)
error: failed to push some refs to ...
```

This is bad, since the user who pushed doesn't get any clue that there's a new commit he needs to pull first.

I expect this might be because the "Your branch is behind" check happens before the hook triggers?

Comment: Yes, the pre-receive hook on the bare server is running far too late in the process. The real flaw seems to be in the step *files on the prime repository get updated by some scripts* as these scripts should not be updating files directly, and in fact, the deployed code probably should not have a Git repository at all. The scripts should update files in a real repository, commit them, and send them to the bare repository. The bare repository's post-receive hook can then deploy any update using a real deployment tool (not raw Git).

Comment: Yeah, ideally the prime repository would never get changed by anything but the hook. However, I have no control over that, as they are created by a CMS.